# Find the axis of reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have to determine the axis of reflection of the composition of a rotation and a reflection, y show that the order of composition matters.

So I multiply the matrices that represent each isometry, with angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ not necessarily the same, and I got:
$$Re\alpha \circ Ro\beta=
\left( 
        \begin{matrix}
        cos 2\alpha & sin 2\alpha \\
        sin 2\alpha & -cos2\alpha & \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)
\left( 
        \begin{matrix}
        cos \beta & -sin \beta \\
        sin \beta & cos \beta& \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)$$
$$=
\left( 
        \begin{matrix}
        cos \beta \;cos2\alpha+sin2\alpha \;sin\beta & -sin \beta \;cos2\alpha+sin2\alpha \;cos\beta\\
        sin 2\alpha \;cos\beta-cos2\alpha \;sin\beta & -sin2\alpha \;sin\beta-cos2\alpha \;sin\beta& \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)$$
Well, then I wanted to write this last matrix as a reflection, 
$\left( 
        \begin{matrix}
        cos \gamma & sin \gamma\\
        sin \gamma & -cos \gamma \\
        \end{matrix}
\right)$, where $\gamma$ would give me the axis, but since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ might not be the same, I don't think I can use the same trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the trigonometric identities 
$$\sin(A\pm B)=\sin A\cos B \pm\cos A\sin B$$
$$\cos(A\pm B)=\cos A\cos B \mp\sin A\sin B$$
For more identities see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Answer (score 1):

By using trigonometric identities for the sum of two angles, you should verify that this last matrix is actually a reflection matrix corresponding to (half) the angle $2\alpha-\beta$. In other words, the first component of the matrix is $\cos(2\alpha-\beta)$, and so on.